# Setting expiry dates using htaccess (Leverage browser caching)

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser, blogs, server

I'm trying to improve the Leverage browser caching for my blog, so I have this in my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 day”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. When I run gtmetrix, I'm still getting this:

```
The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at     least one week in the future for the following resources:

http://kaye.at/img/11/11-month-update.jpg (expiration not specified)
http://kaye.at/img/11/archie-and-cousin-caitlin.jpg (expiration not specified)
http://kaye.at/img/11/archie-and-nanny-bailey.jpg (expiration not specified)
http://kaye.at/img/11/archie-and-nanny.jpg (expiration not specified)
http://kaye.at/img/abc/h@2x.png (expiration not specified)
http://kaye.at/img/anchorlogodark.png (expiration not specified)
http://kaye.at/img/confetti.png (expiration not specified)
https://gwc.lphbs.com/0/lpg/msg (expiration not specified)
http://use.typekit.net/eev2aks.js (10 minutes)
http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js (20 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js (2 hours)
http://helloarchie.blue/themes/tootsweet/css/base.css (1 day)
http://helloarchie.blue/themes/tootsweet/css/layout.css (1 day)
http://helloarchie.blue/themes/tootsweet/css/skeleton-fluid.css (1 day)
```

Comment: Yes it is enabled. Not sure why some formats are expiring but not others. :/

Comment: Gtmetrix takes some time to reflect updated things. Please check once with google page speed about this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are mod\_expires and mod\_headers not working on my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002359/why-are-mod-expires-and-mod-headers-not-working-on-my-server)